# intent with type 'android.intent.action.SEND' doesn't work for expo

Tags: android, react-native, android-intent, instagram, expo

I'm trying to get a solution when I will be able to share images from my app through instagram.

Currently, I try to do it with intent and it looks like so:

```
IntentLauncherAndroid .startActivityAsync('android.intent.action.SEND', {
            type: 'image/*',
            extra: {
              'android.intent.extra.STREAM': encodeURIComponent(uri)
            },
            packageName: 'com.instagram.android'
          })
```

in this case 'uri' variable looks like

```
file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540anonymous%252Frepost-for-free-d795b3f6-6148-4b16-9aa4-b3550402e0a2/images/3.jpg
```

With this solution, I will get the exception

```
Error: Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND cmp=com.viber.voip/.messages.ui.forward.ForwardActivity (has extras) } from ProcessRecord{5e88e89d0 18222:host.exp.exponent/u0a8} (pid=18222, uid=10008) not exported from uid 10216
    at createErrorFromErrorData (D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:146)
    at D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\NativeModules.js:95
    at MessageQueue.__invokeCallback (D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:397)
    at D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:127
    at MessageQueue.__guard (D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:297)
    at MessageQueue.invokeCallbackAndReturnFlushedQueue (D:\projects\repost-for-free\repost-for-free\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:126)
    at debuggerWorker.js:72
```

and I can't understand how to solve this and why do I see there cmp=com.viber.voip/.messages.ui.forward.ForwardActivity ?

if I will replace android.intent.action.SEND to 'android.intent.action.VIEW' it will be able to trigger intent, but it will suggest wrong apps to handle it (some default apps like google maps, contacts, etc).

Maybe I don't set right permissions or there is some specific for calling 'android.intent.action.SEND' intent ? I call my intent after downloading this image (image already exists on my phone when I call the intent).

P.S. I tried to convert Java solution to Expo (JS) solution, which could be found here 'https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/android-intents/'